# Why are the indents visible? Did I press a button?

Tags: openoffice

[image]

So there are dots for spaces and some character every time I hit enter... why are these showing?

Comment: Press `ctrl+f10`

Comment: that `some character` is a paragraph mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've enabled visible spaces. It can be toggled with the "[backwards P](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow)" on the top row.

If you're curious it's called a Pilcrow, ¶.